# Laravel Eloquent Save Item Error?

Tags: php, laravel

When I try saving an item's to my database I get

```
Method Clients::__toString() must return a string value
```

Current code

```
        $name = Input::get('email');
        $client = Input::get('client');
        $website = Input::get('website');
        $userassign = Input::get('userassign');

        $client = new Clients();
        $client->name = $name;
        $client->client = $client;
        $client->website = $website;
        $client->parent = $userassign;


        $client->save();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Lol you again ^^ Why you have `$client = Input::get('client');` and then `$client = new Clients();`? Isn't that weird?

Comment: Im back! Well not really?

Comment: You really should rename the model to `Client`, btw. Like, it would make much better sense. `Client` model by default uses `clients` table, unless you tell it otherwise.

Comment: @MightyPork +1 for spotting Laravel's convention

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're redefining `$client`.

```
        $name = Input::get('email');
        $clientInput = Input::get('client');
        $website = Input::get('website');
        $userassign = Input::get('userassign');

        $client = new Clients(); 
        $client->name = $name; 
        $client->client = $clientInput; //Here was your problem
        $client->website = $website;
        $client->parent = $userassign;


        $client->save();
```